# If $A+B+C=180^{\circ}$, then show that: $\cos B=\sin A\sin C-\cos A\cos C$

Tags: trigonometry

Here is the question :

> If $A+B+C = 180^{\circ}$, then show that: $\cos B = \sin A \sin C - \cos A \cos C$.

EDIT : Here is my reviewed working :

$$
\cos B=-\cos (A+C)
$$

Since $$\space A+B+C = 180^\circ, \space B =180^\circ-(A+C)$$

And 
$$\begin{align}
-\cos B &=\cos (180+B) \\
-\cos B &=\cos(180+(180-(A+C)) \\
-\cos B &=\cos(360-(A+C)) \\
-\cos B &=\cos(A+C) \\
-\cos B &=\cos A \cos C - \sin A \sin C \\
\cos B &= \sin A \sin C - \cos A \cos C \\
\cos B &= -\cos (A+C)
\end{align}$$

Can someone confirm that my working is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: $\cos(B)$ does not equal $\cos(A+C)$. You know $B=180^{\circ}-A-C$ and you can verify $\cos(180^{\circ}-\theta)=-\cos(\theta)$ by looking at a circle, so you're missing a sign at the beginning.

Comment: @anon right, but he never used the first "identity"

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti OP began with $\cos(B)=\cos(A+C)$ in the original version of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first step $\cos(B) = \cos(A+C)$ is incorrect. It should be $\cos(B) = -\cos(A+C)$.

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing this out to me I just realised my mistake

Answer (score 2):

Your first line should be deleted, ok. But the main mistake is at the last line. You write
$$
-\cos(B)=\cos(A+C),
$$
which is fine. But what is $\cos(A+C)$?

Also, more directly: $\cos(x)=-\cos(180-x)$ for all $x$. So $\cos(B)=-\cos(A+C)$.

Comment: Can you check over my working please I just edited my post

Comment: @Conal Everything correct now